# Microsoft Graph: NextLink...what about previous link?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft graph will provide you with “@odata.nextLink”.
How can I get the  “previousLink”. ?

Comment: could you share some more details about the scenario you need a previous link for?

Comment: I'm using Azure Active Directory for my user system.  We have 1000's of users in our system, and it would take to long to download all of them locally.  Instead I want to download users as needed.  For this example, it's a page called users which has a table.

Comment: assume im download 20 users at a time, and you can click next or previous to navigate through the users in the system.  Additionally...Microsoft doesn't support the "$count" command for users which is also frustrating.  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count

Comment: So the request you're trying to express to the Graph is "give me all the X number of users before this specific user" correct?

Comment: Not exactly...if you are to use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users you will be served the first 100 users (you can add top(999) for a larger data set, but it does not go past 1000, and is slow for that many results.

Comment: "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$skiptoken=X%274453707...." is returned from the request, allowing you to skip to the next set of results easily (designed for this use case), but they do not have odata.prevlink....unless im missing something which is why im posting it here

Comment: I do feel it is a design choice, hence why I was trying to understand your scenario better.
When you are enumerating a collection, you always page the collection from the beginning and until the end or until you've found the item you are looking for.
If you need a different ordering for various reasons, you should leverage the $orderby command, but those two capabilities (paging and ordering) should be considered distinct, they do not serve the same purpose

Answer (score 0):

This is a design choice, there is no previous link. When you are enumerating a collection, you always page the collection from the beginning and until the end or until you've found the item you are looking for. If you need a different ordering for various reasons, you should leverage the $orderby command, but those two capabilities (paging and ordering) should be considered distinct, they do not serve the same purpose

Answer (score -1):

I just wanted to give my two cents here and say I am just as confused as you are as to why there is no previous page link.

It's a standard behavior in paginated lists to be able to go forward and back. This really makes no sense at all.

Comment: OData doesn't specify it http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/odata-json-format-v4.01.html#_Toc38457740
feedback for Microsoft Graph can be provided to aka.ms/graphfeedback.